# Why don't programming languages use simplified boolean expressions?

Tags: logic, programming-languages, language-design

I've never understood why we use syntax like this:

`if (a == b || a == c)`

when it could be simplified to something like this:

`if (a == b || c)`

Is this an issue with compilers or something? Can we really not account for a string of code like this and make it work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no technical limitation that would make it impossible (or even too difficult) to implement a language that treats `a == b || c` as a shortcut for `a == b || a == c`. The problem is that it would be almost (?) impossible to come up with rules to do so only in the cases where that's what's expected.

For instance consider the expression `result == null || fileIsClosed` where `fileIsClosed` is a boolean. Surely the programmer would not expect this to be treated as `result == null || result == fileIsClosed`. You could come up with additional rules like "the replacement is only applied if the right operand of `||` is not a boolean", but then the replacement also does not work if you do `booleanResult == possibleResult1 || possibleResult2`. In fact the only thing about this example, that tells us whether the programmer intended for the replacement to happen, are the names of the variables. Obviously the compiler can't infer meaning from variable names, so it'd be impossible to do what the user wants in every case, making simple rules without exceptions (like "`expr1 || expr2` is true iff at least one of `expr1` and `expr2` are true") preferable.

So in summary: We don't want the replacement to take place in all cases and inferring in which cases the replacements would make sense with complete accuracy would be impossible. Since it should be easy to reason about code, implementing a system that may or may not apply the replacement based on rules that 90% of programmers won't know or understand will lead to confusing behavior in certain cases and is therefore not a good idea.

Comment: This makes sense, but I guess I should've made the example `if (a == (b || c))` to make it even clearer that the intention is to compare the 'a' vlaue against n other values.

Comment: @Samir please, don't change the Original sense/logic of your question as it requires changes in all answers.. See: your question is of value to other readers - Go for a new question

Comment: @Samir: Some languages implement it like so: `all(o == a for o in [b, c])` or for the particular case of equality comparison `a in [b, c]`.

Comment: @Samir That replacement would have similar issues when `a`, `b` and `c` are booleans. After all it would be strange if you'd have to write `bool tmp = b || c; if(a == tmp)` to actually get the "real" semantics of `if(a == (b || c))`. Though admittedly I can't think of a real-world example offhand where you'd actually need to check whether one boolean equals the disjunction of two others.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers everyone.

Answer (score 6):

Some part of the answer is: `if (a == b || c)` would not be interpretable without context or knowing the meaning behind this expression.

**Consider the following situation:**

What if `c` would be a boolean expression or a boolean value by itself? It could then be interpreted as either:

1. `if (a has the value of b  OR  c is true)`
2. `if (a has the value of b OR c)`

Now what was the intention when a human being coded these lines? ... *think. We don't exactly know nor does a compiler when it is asked to produce object code to be executed on a machine (as intended by the developer).

Or more drastically: A compiler can (and should) not guess, like humans sometimes do.

Answer (score 1):

You can, you are just using the wrong programming language :)

In [Icon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icon_(programming_language)) for example, you can write `a = (b | c)`. The way that works is that `|` really concatenates sequences, and `=` (equality) filters them (where false is no results, and true is some results). It implements this through back-tracking.

You can do even crazier things, like `write ((0 to 4) > 1) * 3` will print out 6 9 12.

Answer (score 0):

As you already know the string you wrote would have different meaning. However, some languages provide extension to change the behavior of the operator. You can use it if you want to define your own custom operations.